# Rails - sort_by but keep active record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project where I have a pupil model, which has an attribute called level, an integer between 1 and 3. At the moment the default sorting by level has been over ridden:

```
enum level: { "level_1" => 2, "level_2" => 0, "level_3" => 1 }
```

And I've been asked not to change this. I now need to sort by level ascending, and have been using sort_by:

```
pupils.sort_by(&:level_asc)
```

with a method level_asc that just returns their level. The problem with this is it is returning an array which is screwing up my pagination.

Is there any way I can sort by level ascending, ignoring the previously stated rule, and return an active record relation? I've tried attr_accessors with no joy..

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I've tried simply merging 3 where queries, however I'm using rails 4.~ and I don't have access to the 'OR' method which would work perfectly:

```
Pupil.where(level: 1).or(where(level: 2)).or(where(level: 3))
```

If there is any way for me to do the above line in rails 4 then I'll be sorted

Comment: Use order instead of sort_by as sort_by is executed in ruby and  used to sort arrays.

Comment: The default order has been over ridden with the first line of code I pasted, which orders them 2 --> 3 --> 1

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: so, to clarify, you want them in 'level 1' -> 'level 2' -> 'level 3' and the database is an integer that would end up sorting them in 'level 2' -> 'level 3' -> 'level 1'?

Comment: POSTGRES and yes Simple Lime, I want them sorted by integer number ascending however can not change the default enum method already in place

Comment: Sorry, completely overlooked that. Are you allowed to scope it out in the model?

Comment: No worries! And sure I'm allowed to add methods and scopes I just can't figure out how to achieve it while returning a relation

Comment: try this https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified.

Comment: You could do: `Pupil.where("pupil.level = '1'' OR pupil.level = '2'")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the `order` clause, by using something like:

```
Pupil.order('level = 2 DESC, level = 0 DESC, level = 1 DESC, id ASC').collect { |pupil| [pupil.id, pupil.level] }
# Pupil Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "pupils".* FROM "pupils" ORDER BY level = 2 DESC, level = 0 DESC, level = 1 DESC, id ASC
# => [[4, "level_1"], [5, "level_1"], [6, "level_1"], [8, "level_1"], [2, "level_2"], [7, "level_2"], [1, "level_3"], [3, "level_3"], [9, "level_3"], [10, "level_3"]]
```

Comment: Just tried - I get '[123, "level_1"]' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Comment: Hmm, you removed the `collect` I added on the end to show the output?Looks like that got called on the array I was using to showcase the `order` clause worked

Comment: order('level = 2 DESC, level = 0 DESC, level = 1 DESC, last_name ASC').collect { |pupil| [pupil.id, pupil.level] }

Comment: yeah just try whatever you're doing with `Pupil.order('level = 2 DESC, level = 0 DESC, level = 1 DESC, last_name ASC')` that's the part that returns the relation...the `.collect { |pupil| [pupil.id, pupil.level] }` was just executing the query and trimming down the output to the info important to seeing the ordering was working

Comment: Works perfectly without the collect method at the end!! Many many thanks!!